# What happens if an RSA key pair has identical public and private exponents?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

Rather, is it possible for big prime numbers?

Classroom examples usually involve smaller primes, so for example if you are given a prime number pair $p = 3$, $q = 13$ you would get $n = 39$ and $e = d = 5$, making encryption and decryption the same for a message $x$ or ciphertext $x$.

This can be a big problem, e.g. if a server sends you cipher $x$, you can decrypt it and get the message, then you encrypt the cipher $x$ itself and if you get the message again then you know the public key is the same as the private key.

Is this possible in industry?

Comment: @JanDvorak Just comparing the modulus would do it. And searches on the internet have been performed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the public and private exponents will never be the same for real (that is, not toy) RSA keys.

The public exponent is almost always be deliberately chosen as a small value (with 65537, 3 and 17 being the most popular choices).  In contrast, the private exponent will always be a huge value; always at least $(p-1)/e$ (where $p$ is the larger prime factor of the modulus, and $e$ is the public exponent), and will generally (almost always) be much larger than that.  This implies that if you have a 1024-bit RSA key, and a public exponent of 65537, then the private exponent will be at least 495 bits long.

Even if you (for some unknown reason) select a random large public exponent, then it is still extremely unlikely.  If we look into the conditions that allow $d = e$, we see that both of the following must hold:

$e^2 \bmod (p-1) = 1$

$e^2 \bmod (q-1) = 1$

Having even one of $e^2 \bmod (p-1)$ and $e^2 \bmod (q-1)$ to be 1 is extremely unlikely; having both conditions happen is not something to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

As a curious addendum, has there been a case where the public and private key ended up the same? If so, what happened?

Comment: @SchwitJanwityanujit: I have never heard about such a case for a real RSA key.

Comment: Could one create such a key pair intentionally?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: sure, if one wanted to.  The obvious way would involve selecting $p$ and $q$ such that $p-1$ and $q-1$ have known factorization; that'd make selecting the value $e$ straightforward ($e = 1, -1 \bmod r$ for every prime power factor of $p-1$ or $q-1$).

Answer (score -5):

Ciphertext C= 10 sent to user whose public key is e= 5, n = 35
if you calculate d, it will be 5, i.e. e= d = 5.

Comment: The question asks "is it possible for big prime numbers?" and "Is this possible in industry?". This answer does not touch this.